# Who initiates discussions for commercials of movies played on TV?

Tags: commercial

I am watching *What To Expect When You're Expecting* on TNT.  I am noticing a trend among the commercials.  There are several different diaper and baby aids ads.

Who initiates contact for the placement of these ads?

- Does TNT gauge the subject matter and reach out to the appropriate sponsors?
- Do sponsors each monitor the upcoming roster of movies playing on TV and bid on spots?
- Are the studios or production companies each responsible for their own movies in securing sponsorship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does TNT gauge the subject matter and reach out to the appropriate sponsors?

### Essentially, yes.

This is a common practice amongst television networks and production companies.

They show the programmes, or at least selected elements, to advertisers months in advance.

These events are known as the Upfronts.

> In the television industry, an upfront is a gathering at the start of important advertising sales periods, held by television network executives and attended by major advertisers and the media. It is so named because of its main purpose, to allow marketers to buy television commercial airtime "up front", or several months before the television season begins°
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upfront_(advertising))